# Web Applications on IIS

Tags: iis

i am trying to host my site locally on IIS. But when i browse the site i get this error:

```
Server Error in '/baby_boy' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'baby_boy`.SiteMaster'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="baby_boy.SiteMaster" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Source File: baby_boy/Site.master    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237
```

any advice on how to solve this would be much appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `Site.Master`, there is a reference to the classname SiteMaster, in namespace `baby_boy`

is this file present, and in the the same directory as the `Site.Master` file?

or is no SiteMaster class?

In the Site.Master there is a reference to `baby_boy.SiteMaster`, which should read as follows:

```
baby_boy.Site.Master
```

(you are missing one period)

Comment: The Site.Master.cs is in the same directory as Site.Master.

Comment: In that case, there is a spelling mistake in Site.Master. see the revised answer